# Cutting Ceiling Molding Wihtout Removing It?

Tags: woodworking

I want to put up a stud wall to make a walk in wardrobe. I want to get a flush joint against the wall but I have some molding across the top. I was wondering if there is an approach to cutting a grove/slot in it without removing it, it's quite a long piece 15+ foot so ideally I want it to stay where it is.

Comment: When you say "flush" do you actually mean "tight"? They aren't the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to this problem would be to use an oscillating tool, of which there are many brands available. Different blade options are provided with the tool, including a toothsome flat blade with a square face.

Home Depot is one source of these tools and blades:

[image: home depot blade selection]

It won't necessarily be fast, but it will be a clean cut (depending on operator skill). If you need a cheap solution, [Harbor Freight](https://www.harborfreight.com/oscillating-multi-tool-62279.html) is likely to be a good source. They have a twenty dollar (US) tool that does not specify that it comes with the cutter, but those are seven bucks each in the same location.

Comment: Thanks for the info, might be a long trans Atlantic flight to pick up a small cutting tool :). I might look for something similar here in the UK.

Comment: Yes, it is likely that you will find what you require locally. The photos are representative of products you would purchase. I understand that there are Chinese product outlets in the UK.